# Google Chrome Developer Tools data transfer size

Tags: google-chrome, web, gzip

In Google Chrome when using the Network Panel to monitor files being transfered from a site, the total size of the data transfered is given at the bottom of the list. Does this figure reflect the size of the data coming across the wire or the total size of the files after gzip/zlib decompression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page: http://rossb.biz/blog/2013/measuring-page-weight/ the figure reflects the actual size of data coming across the wire.

By my own checking this still seems to be the case as of 2014.